# Arduino to Arduino communication via SoftwareSerial

Tags: arduino

I have two Arduino Leonardo. 
Could these two Arduino boards communicate with each other by SoftwareSerial library? (Not Serial1, Thank you)

Comment: The answer is very probably YES. Is that what you asked or will you refine your question?

Comment: if you had asked this question on google, he woud have definately said yes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use digital pins to do it. Simply connect both Tx to Rx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use any spare digital pins on each Arduino

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. You can use all PWN Pins, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11, 13.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you always have to consider that Arduino is based on *microcrontroler*, not *microprocessor* so when you program it you should forget multitasking, every kind of multitasking attempt will come in unexpected behaviour (slowdown close to stuck).
In this case software serial communication will slow down program execution according to the volume of data received and it will be completely stuck during hardware serial communication.
To deal with that you should use the approach "one thing at time" in your code.
I hope it helped and didn't frighten.

Answer (score 1):

There's is an example in the Arduino IDE under software serial that shows how to use it. It says to use digital pins 3 and 4 instead of the hardware serial pins 0 and 1. The sketch constantly reads the software serial and prints anything it reads to the serial monitor.

It wouldn't take much to adapt this code to run on a second Arduino to constantly write to Software Serial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Simply use TX and RX pins of arduino. Connect the receiver TX, RX pins to RX, TX of the sender, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

of course , just make sure to cross out RX and TX:

RX1 -> TX2

RX2 -> TX1

Answer (score 0):

You can use any digital pins as software serial, in case i doesn't work, use pin 10, 11 for software serial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SerialTransfer.h](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/SerialTransfer) to automatically packetize and parse your data for inter-Arduino communication without the headace. The library is installable through the Arduino IDE and includes many examples.

Here are the library's features:

> This library:
>
> - can be downloaded via the Arduino IDE's Libraries Manager (search "SerialTransfer.h")
> - works with "software-serial" libraries
> - is non blocking
> - uses packet delimiters
> - uses consistentoverhead byte stuffing
> - uses CRC-8 (Polynomial 0x9B with lookup table)
> - allows the use of dynamically sized packets (packets can have payload lengths anywhere from 1 to 255 bytes)
> - can transfer bytes, ints, floats, and even structs!!

Example TX Arduino Sketch:

```
#include "SerialTransfer.h"

SerialTransfer myTransfer;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  myTransfer.begin(Serial1);
}

void loop()
{
  myTransfer.txBuff[0] = 'h';
  myTransfer.txBuff[1] = 'i';
  myTransfer.txBuff[2] = '\n';

  myTransfer.sendData(3);
  delay(100);
}
```

Example RX Arduino Sketch:

```
#include "SerialTransfer.h"

SerialTransfer myTransfer;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  myTransfer.begin(Serial1);
}

void loop()
{
  if(myTransfer.available())
  {
    Serial.println("New Data");
    for(byte i = 0; i < myTransfer.bytesRead; i++)
      Serial.write(myTransfer.rxBuff[i]);
    Serial.println();
  }
  else if(myTransfer.status < 0)
  {
    Serial.print("ERROR: ");
    Serial.println(myTransfer.status);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the pwm pins to communicate. It is recommended to not use 0,1 for serial communication as they are used to upload the sketches using the USB port into the Arduino.